Contraction of a loop curve on an algebraic surface.
Let $S$ be a smooth algebraic surface over ${\Bbb C}$. Suppose we have a connected curve $C$ whose each irreducible component $C_1, \ldots, C_n$ is ${\Bbb P}^1$, i.e., a rational curve. Suppose that the intersection matrix $A \in {\Bbb M}_n({\Bbb R})$ of which $(i, j)$-component is the intersection number $(C_i, C_j)$ is negative definite. Let us denote by ${\Gamma}_C$ the dual graph of $C$, which is a one-dimensional connected simplicial complex.
Q. If ${\mathrm{rank}}_{\Bbb Z}H_1({\Gamma}_C, {\Bbb Z}) = 0$, i.e. ${\Gamma}_C$ is a tree, I have heard that $C$ can be always contracted to a point, which is not necessarilly a smooth point. However when ${\mathrm{rank}}_{\Bbb Z}H_1({\Gamma}_C, {\Bbb Z}) = 1$, i.e. ${\Gamma}_C$ is a closed loop, $C$ is said that it cannot be always contracted to a point on an algebraic surface. How can I intuitively know this fact?
It seems that well-known results ensure only the case where ${\mathrm{rank}}_{\Bbb Z}H_1({\Gamma}_C, {\Bbb Z}) = 0$, i.e. sufficiently rational. Is there any sufficient criterion for contractions for a non-rational curve $C$?
